# Browser bloqueando renderização de fonte

Tags: html5, css3, font

Criei umas fontes personalizadas para ícones utilizando o `IcoMoon`, e estou utilizando o `Live Server` como "servidor" de testes em um simples site com  as seguintes tecnologias:

- `HTML5`
- `CSS3`
- `JS VANILLA`
- `BOOTSTRAP`

Ao testar o icon abrindo normalmente o `index.html` o mesmo funciona sem problemas, porém ao testar o icon utilizando o `Live Server` eu recebo o seguinte `error` no `console`:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/fonts/icons/instagramicons.ttf?edyqz0 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'instagramicons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style:  normal;
  src:  url('../fonts/icons/instagramicons.eot?edyqz0');
  src:  url('../fonts/icons/instagramicons.eot?edyqz0#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/icons/instagramicons.ttf?edyqz0') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/icons/instagramicons.woff?edyqz0') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/icons/instagramicons.svg?edyqz0#instagramicons') format('svg');
}

i {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'instagramicons' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-logotype:before {
  content: "\e900";
}
```

```html
<i class="icon-logotype"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema que estava ocorrendo era que minha extensão `AdBlock` estava impedindo que as fontes fossem renderizadas no meu servidor local com a extensão `Live Server` no `Visual Studio Code`.

Então para resolver o problema, eu simplesmente removi a execução do mesmo em todas as minhas páginas do meu servidor local `http://127.0.0.1:5500/*`.

**NOTA**

> Tomem cuidado ao utilizar algum tipo de bloqueador no seu browser, ele pode te trazer diversos problemas em desenvolvimento, como este.